# Swift 4 - Get the Longest array in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Dictionary like so:

```
var tableData = Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>>()
```

My tableData Dictionary may have 71 or 72 values in it. Currently I am just grabbing the first one to get a count of these values:

```
var counter = (Array(tableData.values)[0] as Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>).count
```

My question is, how do I get the item that has the most values? So my counter is 72 all the time and not 71?

Does this make sense?

Comment: `let max = tableData.values.max { $0.count > $1.count } ?? 0`?

Comment: Trying that now, stand by

Comment: Okay, my count returns 75, which is the number, which is the number of items I have  in the directory, what I am trying to do is number of the most amount of dictionary items in those arrays.

Comment: So, can you think of a possible way to expand on it? Maybe start with `$0.values.count`??? (as an idea of the top of my head)

Comment: Can I see an example?

Comment: I though that was

Comment: I tried this `let counter = tableData.values.max { $0.values.count > $1.values.count }` but I get an error `Value of type 'Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>' has no member 'values'`

Comment: `tableData.values.max { ($0.max { $0.count > $1.count }?.count ?? 0) > ($1.max { $0.count > $1.count }?.count ?? 0)` as a "off the top of my, I don't know what I'm doing, head" ;)

Comment: I get a warning here `Result of operator '>' is unused` on the second one.

Comment: Okay, expand it into it's full form, rather then trying to cheat like I did and doing it short hand ... which highlighted a logic bomb :('

Comment: @user979331 What domain does this code model? I'm writing an answer, but it's quite hard to talk about it without having names to label things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, it's worth doing things long handed...

```
var tableData = Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>>()

tableData["Test2"] = [["A": "", "B": "", "C": ""]]
tableData["Test"] = [["A": "", "B": ""], ["A": "", "B": "", "C": "", "D": ""]]

let result = tableData.values.max { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    let lhsValue = lhs.max(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
        return lhs.count < rhs.count
    })
    let rhsValue = rhs.max(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
        return lhs.count < rhs.count
    })
    return lhsValue?.count ?? 0 < rhsValue?.count ?? 0
}
result
let longest = result?.max(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs.count < rhs.count
})
longest?.count
```

Which will output something like...

```
result = [["A": "", "B": ""], ["B": "", "A": "", "C": "", "D": ""]]
longest?.count = 4
```

If this isn't doing what you want, consider taking the the idea and running with it to and seeing where it takes you ;)